# Back to the line after Remark and theorem

Tags: theorems

I write the following code:

```
  \newtheoremstyle{examplestyle}{10mm}{10mm}{\slshape}{2pt}{\bfseries}{\newline}{10mm}{}
  \theoremstyle{examplestyle}
```

to be able to get theorems look like this

```
Theorme:
bla bla bla bla
```

but it should not apply to remarks, for which I would like this

```
   remark : bla bla bla
```

and not

```
  remark:
  bla bla bla
```

when I write like this

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[francais]{babel}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{microtype}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{hyperref}%

\hypersetup{pdfstartview=XYZ}%
\newtheoremstyle{examplestyle}{10mm}{10mm}{\slshape}{2pt}{\bfseries}{\newline}{10mm}{}
\theoremstyle{examplestyle}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Théorème}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Définition}
\newtheorem{corollory}[theorem]{Corollaire}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemme}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remarque}
\newtheorem{property}[theorem]{Propriété}
\newtheorem{demonstration}[theorem]{Démonstration.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\alph{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
bla bla bla 
\end{theorem}

\begin{property}
\begin{itemize}
\item Si X est une variable aléatoire de loi N(m, t) alors 
\[ \mathbb{E}(\exp(zX))=\exp(\frac{tz^{2}}{2}+mz), \hspace{4mm} \forall z \in \mathbb{C} ;\]
\item Si X suit une loi $\mathcal{N}(m,t)$, alors $a+bX$ suit une loi $\mathcal{N}(a+bm,b^{2}t).$ ;
\item Si $X$ et $Y$ sont deux variables aléatoires indépendantes suivant respectivement les lois $\mathcal{N}(a,t)$ et $N(b,s),$ alors $X+Y$ suit la loi $\mathcal{N}(a+b,t+s).$.
\end{itemize}
...\end{property}
\begin{property}
\
\begin{itemize}
\item Si X est une variable aléatoire de loi N(m, t) alors 
\[ \mathbb{E}(\exp(zX))=\exp(\frac{tz^{2}}{2}+mz), \hspace{4mm} \forall z \in \mathbb{C} ;\]
\item Si X suit une loi $\mathcal{N}(m,t)$, alors $a+bX$ suit une loi $\mathcal{N}(a+bm,b^{2}t).$ ;
\item Si $X$ et $Y$ sont deux variables aléatoires indépendantes suivant respectivement les lois $\mathcal{N}(a,t)$ et $N(b,s),$ alors $X+Y$ suit la loi $\mathcal{N}(a+b,t+s).$.
\end{itemize}
\end{property}
\end{document}
```

I want both Theorems and Remarks have the body on a new line.

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Furthermore, please provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that); a lot of the packages are not necessary.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Do you want your theorems to have the body on a new line, but remarks to have a different style with the body immediately after the heading "Remarque"?

Comment: no Mr  Gonzalo Medina i want both theorems and remaks have the body on a new line

Answer (score 2):

you have the `\newline` argument in the wrong place for `amsthm`.  here's what you have:

```
\newtheoremstyle{examplestyle}{10mm}{10mm}{\slshape}{2pt}{\bfseries}{\newline}{10mm}{}
```

here's what the instructions say you should have:

```
\newtheoremstyle{examplestyle}{10mm}{10mm}{\slshape}{2pt}{\bfseries}{}{\newline}{}
```

(i'm not quite sure what you're after with the `10mm`, so i've left it out.)

you have put the `\newline` where `\newtheoremstyle` is looking for the punctuation
that you want to follow the heading.  the *next* argument should be "the space after
the thm head", where `\newline` = line break.

one problem with this is that when it's followed directly by a list, there is
extra space inserted, and (owing to the way lists are defined), this may result
in the heading being left alone at the bottom of a page.  i don't know of a good
automatic fix for this.

Comment: no it's not what i want here 's my question i want both theorems and remaks have the body on a new line